# event to modify sibling element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In a web page, I have a grid of divs. In each div are 3 divs, the 2nd is hidden, I want it so that when the user hovers over the 3rd div, the 1st div becomes hidden and the 2nd is displayed.

I'm using jquery.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="hello">hello</div>
  <div class="who">sailor
  </div>
  <div onmouseover="whoOn();" onmouseout="whoOff();" class="hover">hover me</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="hello">hello</div>
  <div class="who">dolly
  </div>
  <div onmouseover="whoOn();" onmouseout="whoOff();" class="hover">hover me</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="hello">hello</div>
  <div class="who">kitty
  </div>
  <div onmouseover="whoOn();" onmouseout="whoOff();" class="hover">hover me</div>
</div>
```

[Here's a Codepen](http://codepen.io/jakepeg/pen/QNxEEj)

Answer (score 2):

Your whoOn and whoOff methods can be combined like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="hello">hello</div>
  <div class="who">sailor
  </div>
  <div onmouseover="whoBoth(this);" onmouseout="whoBoth(this);" class="hover">hover me</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function whoBoth(target) {
  $(target).siblings(".hello, .who").toggle();
}
```